# Issues with List.Add method when using a variable in C#

Tags: c#, list

I currently am unable to use a variable that is a string to Add as an item to a list.  It simply returns null when I pull the list later:

```
public class JobStatus
{

    public static string _JobURI;
    public static string currentStatus = "no job";

    public static void checkStatus()
    {

        ...
        //define job URI
        List<string> jobURIs = new List<string>();
        jobURIs.Add(_JobURI);
```

However, when I insert a string value like below instead of a variable, it adds it properly to the list:

```
//define job URI
List<string> jobURIs = new List<string>();
jobURIs.Add("new item name");
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Do you ever set a value for `_JobURI`?

Comment: Do you ever assign a value to `_JobURI`? It's null by default.

Comment: Did you initialize _JobURI? It looks like it is still null in your example.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your posted code, the reason you are getting null for `_JobsURI` is that you declare it here:

```
public static string _JobURI;
```

But you never assign it a value.  Per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx): "A string that has been declared but has not been assigned a value is **null**."

Try assigning a value to `_JobURI` and then adding it to the `List<string>`:

```
public static string _JobURI = "Some string here.";
```

Comment: It was assigned a variable from another class.  If I declare it here, would that get overwrite the value I'm trying to apply?

Comment: Can you update the question with the code where you set the variable?   Note that declaring and initializing a variable are two separate things - a declared variable that is not initialized will be null for a reference type or have a default value for a value type.  With the currently posted code it's a guessing game as to what the issue is.

Comment: Tim, are you wanting the corrected code or the original?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, beginning programmer mistake.  I used the Get Set method in the same class and declared the variable as well you all suggested above:

```
public static string currentStatus = "no job";

        private static string joburi = "";
        public static string JobURI
        {
            get { return joburi; }
            set { joburi = value; }
        }
```

Thank you for your help.